# Writing C++ (or other) code using lisp

Tags: c++

I was wondering if are existing tools or package to write C++ (or other langage) code from lisp.

For example, this afternoon I needed to create 4 basic classes:

```
    class D{
    public:
        D(){
        }
    };
    
    class C{
    public:
        C(){
        }
    };
    
    class B{
    public:
        B(){
        }
    };
    
    class A{
    public:
        A(){
        }
    };
```

Using lisp it would be fairly easy to create a function that takes as an argument the class name and generate the template code from one instance:

```
    class $TAG{
    public:
        $TAG(){
        }
    };
```

where $TAG is going to be replaced by the class name.

I am not really looking at the exact lisp code to produce this because I can code it myself but rather at a package about this philosophy and with extra stuff I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like a job for [YASnippet](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/)

The philosophy behind it is to shorten the amount of keystrokes to enter frequently used structures and to not repeat yourself while writing the boilerplate code.

YASnippet comes with a lot of useful snippets preloaded for many major modes. In case of C++ it means that you can type for example `cls` and `Tab` and it will expand to

```
class Name
{
public:
  Name();
  virtual ~Name();
};
```

The cursor will be positioned on `Name` and as you type your name it will replace all occurrences of `Name` to create a valid C++ class.

To initialize YASnippet I use the following code:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure    yasnippet
  :init      (setq yas-verbosity 1)
  :config    (progn
               (yas-global-mode 1)
               (let* ((yas-elpa-snippets-folder (car (file-expand-wildcards
                                                      (concat user-emacs-directory "elpa/yasnippet-*/snippets"))))
                      (yas-folder-candidates  `(,yas-elpa-snippets-folder
                                                ,(concat user-emacs-directory "snippets"))))

                 (cl-loop for p in yas-folder-candidates
                          unless (file-exists-p p)
                          do (cl-delete p yas-folder-candidates))

                 (setq yas-snippet-dirs yas-folder-candidates))
               (yas-reload-all)
               (define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c <tab>") 'yas/insert-snippet))
  :diminish  yas-minor-mode)
```

I've adapted it from what I found on the internet, probably from [emacs-rimero-setup](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/emacs-rimero-setup/blob/master/emacs.d/modules/ers-snippets.el). It uses the wonderful `use-package` to install and initialize YASnippet.

Comment: Great that's exactly what I was looking for!